# Debugger do not stop on breakpoint outside basedir

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

i have an application in the base folder is in the index.php a require to '../application/index.php'. Mappings in IDE is all fine and the remote error show me a debug point on second file.

But it will not break on the breakpoints. Only when i make a breakpoint in the first file i can step into the required index.php and can walk forward. But it will not run to next breakpoint. The first breakpoint working is when the applications comes back to basedirectory. I am using the newest versions. It is remote in a vagrant box.

Thank you

Comment: I get this too, but only sometimes.  I just live with it  :-)  It's not the subfolder that is the issue, I think it doesn't do it for include files.